# Is there a simpler way to do conditional table selection in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to reuse a stored procedure that does the exact same thing for 2 different projects. Here is a sample of it

```sql
DECLARE @id BIGINT;
DECLARE @scenario1 BIGINT;
DECLARE @scenario2 BIGINT;

SET @scenario1 =
(
    SELECT h.id
    FROM firstScenerio p
    INNER JOIN user h
        ON p.id= h.id
    WHERE h.id = @inputID
);

SET @scenario2 =
(
    SELECT h.id
    FROM secondScenerio p
    INNER JOIN user h
        ON p.id= h.id
    WHERE h.id = @inputID
);

SET @iHouseholdID =
(
    CASE
        WHEN @project1Request = true
            THEN @scenario1 
            ELSE @scenario2 
    END
)
```

The only thing that changes in this code is the table being selected (`FROM firstScenerio p` or `FROM secondScenerio p`). Is there a way to have it conditionally select the table to simplify this method? All I need to do is assign `@id` to the id coming from `firstScenerio` or `secondScenerio` table.

```sql
SET @id=
(
    SELECT h.id
    FROM table p
    INNER JOIN user h
        ON p.id= h.id
    WHERE h.id = @inputID
);
```

Above is how the procedure used to be. I need to dynamically change the table depending on the project it is coming from (it is determined by `true` or `false`)

Comment: Are there only two tables or have you simplified?

Comment: Only with dynamic SQL. I would recommend against that. T-SQL does not lend itself well to DRY principles.

Comment: You can create a synonym in the beginning of procedure that points to either table and then select from that synonym. This has some downsides though: 1) you need to remember clean up the synonym 2) if multiple calls are sent, there might be crashes 3) it adds complexity. Another variant is to create a dynamic sql string and then execute it

Comment: Can you not use an `IF` statement to determine which query to run? That would be the most common way of dealing with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are really only two options, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @iHouseholdID = id
FROM 
(
  SELECT h.id 
    FROM dbo.firstScenario AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.user AS h
    ON p.id = h.id
    WHERE @project1Request = 1
    AND h.id = @inputID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT h.id  
    FROM dbo.secondScenario AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.user AS h
    ON p.id = h.id
    WHERE @project1Request = 0
    AND h.id = @inputID
) AS sub;
```

It may even work okay this way, though it is less intuitive to defer the join to `user` (it still might be an ok execution plan):

```
SELECT TOP (1) @iHouseholdID = id
FROM 
(
  SELECT h.id FROM 
  (
    SELECT id 
      FROM dbo.firstScenario
      WHERE @project1Request = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id  
      FROM dbo.secondScenario
      WHERE @project1Request = 0
  ) AS h
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.user AS u
      WHERE u.id = h.id
        AND u.id = @inputID
  )
) AS sub;
```

The dynamic SQL option, included for completeness. If this is the more attractive option because your actual scenario involves too many tables to use either of the above approaches, I think there is a design flaw that deserves more attention than DRY.

```
DECLARE @t sysname = CASE @project1Request
  WHEN 1 THEN N'firstScenario'
         ELSE N'secondScenario' END;

DECLARE @iHouseholdID int, @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
  SELECT @iHouseholdID = h.id
    FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@t) + N' AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.user AS h
    ON p.id = h.id
    WHERE h.id = @inputID;'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
  N'@iHouseholdID int output, @inputID int',
  @iHouseholdID = @iHouseholdID output, 
  @inputID = @inputID;
```

- [Examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/vXvC73Mo)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some conditional logic to determine which query to run would be simpler. Something like this.

```
if @Project1Request = 'true'
    begin
        SELECT @iHouseholdID = h.id
        FROM firstScenerio p
        INNER JOIN user h
            ON p.id= h.id
        WHERE h.id = @inputID
    end
else
    begin
        SELECT @iHouseholdID = h.id
        FROM secondScenerio p
        INNER JOIN user h
            ON p.id= h.id
        WHERE h.id = @inputID
    end
```